# How to depict multidimentional vectors on two-dinesional plot?

Tags: data-visualization, multidimensional-array

I have a **set of vectors** in **multidimensional space** (may be several thousands of dimensions). In this space, I can calculate **distance** between 2 vectors (as a cosine of the angle between them, if it matters). What I want is to **visualize** these vectors keeping the distance. That is, if vector `a` is closer to vector `b` than to vector `c` in multidimensional space, it also must be closer to it on 2-dimensional plot. Is there any kind of diagram that can clearly depict it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Imagine any twodimensional picture of a tetrahedron. There is no way of depicting the four vertices in two dimensions with equal distances from each other. So you will have a hard time trying to depict more than three n-dimensional vectors in 2 dimensions conserving their mutual distances.
(But right now I can't think of a rigorous proof.)

Update:
Ok, second idea, maybe it's dumb: If you try and find clusters of closer associated objects/texts, then calculate the center or mean vector of each cluster. Then you can reduce the problem space. At first find a 2D composition of the clusters that preserves their relative distances. Then insert the primary vectors, only accounting for their relative distances within a cluster and their distance to the center of to two or three closest clusters.

This approach will be ok for a large number of vectors. But it will not be accurate in that there always will be somewhat similar vectors ending up at distant places.

Comment: I thought about it, but there's [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma), which states that a small set of points in high-dimensional space can be projected into a lower dimension  space in such a way that distances between the points are nearly preserved. Also I don't need to keep exactly _Euclidean distance_ - any kind of diagram (histogram, dendrogram, etc.), that can show the distance, is appropriate. For now I'm thinking about graph, where vertices are points and thickness of arcs show distance. Though, I hope there's a better option.

Comment: I understand, didn't know that lemma. Can you explain the problem domain? Maybe there is a different idea.

Comment: @jammon: It is for text clustering/associating. I use [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) to find similar documents, but putting it on the plot isn't trivial. I'm also thinking of using something like [Circos](http://flowingdata.com/2009/02/06/ranking-and-mapping-scientific-knowledge-eigenfactor/#more-1329), though, I still haven't clear idea, how to do it.

Comment: @ffriend: Oh, very interesting topic! But I'm afraid I'm not much of a help.

Comment: @jammon: I'll give a try to your second idea and return with results, thanks.

Comment: I'm looking forward to your results!

Comment: @jammon: I've tried your idea, and for well-separated clusters it gave quite pretty results. Unfortunately, my data isn't so well-separated, so I moved to Circos. For me it gave a bit better results, though I used only about 100 points, and I believe that with more points (say, several thousands) it may seem a bit "entangled". Right now I haven't good illustrations, so I'll update question with images when I'll be completely done. Also, I accept this answer both to thank you and to indicate, that there are some possible options for such visualization in the comments to your answer.

Comment: @ffriend: Thank you for coming back on that!

Comment: @ffriend: I just read about [Force-based algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_(graph_drawing)), which comes close to what i had in mind. A there is an [implementation using javascript and svg](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html)!

Comment: t-SNE might be worth a shot.